# Counting the number of letters in a variable using a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to write code that will take a input of letters and return an output of saying how many times those letters appeared in the variable. 
Here's what I have so far:

```
#Letter Count
def letter_count(letters):
  number_counts = {'a':'1','b':'2','c':'3','d':'4','e':'5','f':'6','g':'7','h':'8','i':'9','j':'10','k':'11','l':'12','m':'13','n':'14','o':'15','p':'16','q':'17','r':'18','s':'19','t':'20','u':'21','v':'22','w':'23','x':'24','y':'25','z':'26'}
  str_int = str(letters)
  int_name = ''
  for char in str_int:
    int_name = int_name + number_counts[char] + ' '
  return int_name.strip()
```

Instead of returning something like, a : 1 or u : 0, it will return 1 or 21
Here's some test cases of what it should do and what it does now

```
#What it should do
letter_count(arthur)
{'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 0, 'd': 3, 'e': 5, 'f': 2, 'g': 4, 'h': 0, 'i': 7, 'j': 0, 'k': 0, 'l': 1, 'm': 3, 'n': 9, 'o': 7, 'p': 1, 'q': 0, 'r': 5, 's': 10, 't': 5, 'u': 1, 'v': 1, 'w': 2, 'x': 0, 'y': 2, 'z': 0}
letter_count('')
{'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 0, 'e': 0, 'f': 0, 'g': 0, 'h': 0, 'i': 0, 'j': 0, 'k': 0, 'l': 0, 'm': 0, 'n': 0, 'o': 0, 'p': 0, 'q': 0, 'r': 0, 's': 0, 't': 0, 'u': 0, 'v': 0, 'w': 0, 'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'z': 0}
#what it does now
letter_count(abc)
1 2 3
letter_count(hi)
8 9
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: for `letter_count('arthur')` it should return `{'a': 1, 'r': 2, 't': 1, 'h': 1, 'u': 1}` right?

Comment: I don't follow how you're supposed to get from 'arthur' to `'m': 3`, or `'n': 9` is this a mistake? I'll write my answer assuming @Ch3steR is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code currently just returns the associated number (e.g. its position in the alphabet) with each letter in in `number_counts` rather than actually trying to count anything.

Instead, lets create a blank dictionary of letters (e.g. they're all initially zero) and add one to each when we encounter that letter in the string we've been given.

```py
def letter_counter(your_string: str):
    counter_dict = {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 0, 'e': 0, 'f': 0, 'g': 0, 'h': 0, 'i': 0, 'j': 0, 'k': 0, 'l': 0, 'm': 0, 'n': 0, 'o': 0, 'p': 0, 'q': 0, 'r': 0, 's': 0, 't': 0, 'u': 0, 'v': 0, 'w': 0, 'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'z': 0}
    for char in your_string.lower():  # I assume you wish to count lower and uppercase as the same
        if char in counter_dict.keys():  # discards anything not in our dictionary
            counter_dict[char] += 1
    return counter_dict

test = "This is a test!"
print(letter_counter(test))
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 0, 'e': 1, 'f': 0, 'g': 0, 'h': 1, 'i': 2, 'j': 0, 'k': 0, 'l': 0, 'm': 0, 'n': 0, 'o': 0, 'p': 0, 'q': 0, 'r': 0, 's': 3, 't': 3, 'u': 0, 'v': 0, 'w': 0, 'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'z': 0}
```

With this you could expand on it to count other characters like `!`, otherwise they're just ignored. If you wish to count upper case letters separately you'd need to add all the uppercase letters to the dict separately, and remove the `.lower()` from the script.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct fix to your current code but just wanted to leave this option here which aims to solve your function goal.
It uses the collections.Counter and transform the result from most_common() into a dict

```
import string
import collections

alphabet_dict = dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_lowercase, 0) 
alphabet_dict.update(dict(collections.Counter(list('arthur')).most_common()))
>>> {'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 0, 'e': 0, 'f': 0, 'g': 0, 'h': 1, 'i': 0, 'j': 0, 'k': 0, 'l': 0, 'm': 0, 'n': 0, 'o': 0, 'p': 0, 'q': 0, 'r': 2, 's': 0, 't': 1, 'u': 1, 'v': 0, 'w': 0, 'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'z': 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Counting the occurrence of letters in a word**

```
myStr = 'linuxandunixrocks'

counter = {}

for char in myStr:

  if char not in counter:

    counter[char] = 1

  else:

    counter[char] = counter[char] + 1

print(counter)

"""
{'l': 1, 'i': 2, 'n': 3, 'u': 2, 'x': 2, 'a': 1, 'd': 1, 'r': 1, 'o': 1, 'c': 1, 'k': 1, 's': 1}
"""
```

**return an output of saying how many times those letters appeared in the variable**

```
myStr = 'linuxandunixrocks'

checkStrs = 'liku'

counter = {}

for char in checkStrs:

  if char in myStr:

    counter[char] = myStr.count(char)


print(counter)

"""
{'l': 1, 'i': 2, 'k': 1, 'u': 2}
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Collections lib u can achieve this

```
from collections import Counter
def letter_count(arthur):
    return dict(Counter(arthur))

print(letter_count('arthur'))
```

---

**Output :**

```
output =  {'a': 1, 'r': 2, 't': 1, 'h': 1, 'u': 1}
```